# Visual Studio 2012 not integrating properly with TFS explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I drag a file in Solution Explorer I expect TFS to perform a matching move.  It doesn't.  Similarly if I rename a file/add/delete I have to repeat the operation in TFS explorer.  They are two separate programs that inhabit the same shell by coincidence.

Can I get them to play better together?  Back in the old days I recall a Source Control Bindings dialog.  I cannot find that in my VS2012.

Full disclosure.  I use both TFS and SVN/Ankh on this machine.  I frequently change Tools | Options | Source Control to swap between the two.  It does not seem connected to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Source Control Bindings dialog.  File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Source Control.  The crucial part is that you do not see this menu item when you are looking at the Source Control Explorer tab.  I opened a code file to get to it.

Once in the dialog I discovered that the solution, and hence the projects, were not bound to source control.  They (TFS and Visual Studio) really were two independent applications sharing a common shell.  Once bound to source control things are integrated as I think they should be.