# TFS 2012 Source Control Explorer only shows my check outs

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I open the Source Control Explorer in VS2012 I can only see what files I have checked out.  If my co-worker checks out a file I cannot see a red check mark, it does not say "edit" under the Pending Changes column, there is no name listed under the User column.  There is no indication that the file is checked out at all.

Same thing in reverse.  He cannot see which files I have checked out.  So far we experimented with only 2 Team Projects.  One was a Web Site project the other a Web Services (asmx) project.

I found this [Visual Studio 2012 not integrating properly with TFS explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124419/visual-studio-2012-not-integrating-properly-with-tfs-explorer)
When I go to File|Source Control|Advanced I do not see a "Change Source Control" option.

Suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK this is intentional, you have to deactivate this behaviour through configuration. This makes your life much easier if you develop offline. Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014746/tfs-2012-disable-multiple-check-out-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How embarrassing...we just figured it out.

The Team Project allows multiple check-outs, so it makes sense that we were both able to check out the file(s), the issue was that we couldn't see which files the other had checked out.

Part of my issue was I had "Team Project 1" open in my Team Explorer, but a solution from "Team Project 2" open in Visual Studio.  So I think that's why I couldn't see the "Change Source Control" option.  As soon as I changed the Team Project in Team Explorer I was able to see the "Change Source Control" option (File|Source Control|Advanced|Change Source Control).

Once I opened the "Change Source Control" screen I saw that my solution and project were unbound.  I bound them.  Then I went to my co-worker's machine, his were also unbound.  I bound them.  We are able to see each other's check-outs in Source Control Explorer now.

Comment: Interesting!  Also, in 2012 the default is *local workspaces* so you won't see each others changes.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278842/tfs-workspaces-across-vs-2010-and-2012